# how to subscribe to back end data in angular js2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

export class Search {

```
data: string;
prop: string = 'connenct';
details: ISearch[];
constructor(public http: Http,public _profileservice: GetSocietyList) {
    this.http = http;
      this._profileservice.getSocietyList()
              .subscribe(
               response => {
                    this.details = response;

            })
        })

}
```

Here i am subscribing the whole response to details but i want only some part of my details i.e where connection_status = 3 and 4.Can some one please  suggest help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter what you need

```
response => {
  this.details = response.filter(
    r => r.connection_status === 3 || r.connnection_status === 4);
```